# Can visibility be "gained" and "lost"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, nouns

Is it appropriate to use the verbs **"gain"** and **"lose**" with the noun **"visibility"**? If not, what can be used instead to describe something that can change its state from visible to hidden and vice versa?

Comment: Both gain visibility and lose visibility are correct English collocations.

Comment: Are you asking about the state of visibility as a physical property? or a figurative usage?

Comment: @Vekzhivi as a physical property

Answer (score 2):

Some**one** can "gain visibility", but in the sense that you described I believe you are talking about some**thing**. We would use "gain visibility" when talking about a person's visibility amongst senior management in a workplace, e.g. "giving the presentation enabled him to gain visibility with the directors", however it wouldn't be used for items/objects.

In your case I would suggest to use the phrases "to become visible" and "to become invisible" as this is more appropriate for items/objects.

Answer (score 2):

*Visibility* has [several definitions](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/visibility):

> 1 the state of being able to see or be seen.
>
> 1.1  the distance one can see as determined by light and weather conditions.
>
> 1.2 The degree to which something has attracted general attention; prominence.

An example that immediately comes to mind is with airplane pilots, who gain or lose visibility (def 1.1) when dealing with clouds or fog.

It's also not uncommon to talk about the *visibility* of people or public services, in terms of how well the public pays attention to what they are doing:

> Trump gained enormous visibility after the first Republican debate, where he completely *mopped the floor* with the other candidates and showed himself to be the crowd favorite.

In the same way "to lose visibility" can be used as a synonym for "fade into obscurity".

> The esteemed professor was well-known during the 1950s for his public lectures on human development, but afterwards he quickly lost visibility when he stopped lecturing, and the public lost interest in the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but is that really the correct term for your intended use?

When talking about an object that changes its state so that it cannot be seen at all, it "becomes invisible" or "disappears." If it changes state so it can be seen even a little bit it "becomes visible" or "appears."

If we're discussing elements in a layered image, video, or website, you "**increase**" or "**decrease**" *opacity* (not "visibility") to make an object more or less opaque/transparent. The object itself in this case could be said to "gain" or "lose" opacity. It only gains/loses "visibility" when it either totally disappears, or slightly appears.

If there is no gradual transition between states, it "appears" or "disappears."

If there is a transition over time it could be said to "fade in" or "fade out."

The object could "become [opaque](https://www.google.com/search?q=opaque)" if its state changes to appear 100% solid - you cannot see other objects through or behind it.

It could become "translucent" or "partially transparent" if you can see the object but can also see other objects inside or directly behind it.

"Gaining/losing visibility" typically refers to the examples given in previous answers, so if you're not talking about people then "gain/lose visibility" might not be what you're looking for:

A pilot "loses visibility" when flying through clouds, or a SCUBA diver "loses visibility" in hazy water. Their ability to see very far decreases due to conditions.

A person "gains" visibility by doing something to bring attention to themselves.